# UI disappear after gradient background

Tags: swift, gradient

when I add a gradient color on my view, all of my UI disappear.

I don't know why because it's just the background that I change.

```
func createGradientLayer() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "#783CBD", alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor().HexToColor(hexString: "#BC1FFF", alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that method `addSublayer` by default adds a new view on top of all other views (and hide them).

You need to add sublayer under all other views

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: @JamesDreeaMz if it works please upvote and mark the answer as correct